# CUPS "Waiting for job to complete."

Tags: server, brother, cups-lpd

When I print via `lp -d brother4 /srv/data2/xfer/TestLabel.3` to a Brother QL-820NWB networked printer, I get the label that I expect. However, the job seems to never be complete in the eyes of CUPS, so I cannot print the next label.

I am migrating some print services from a Windows server to a new UBUNTU server and printing the same file printed on the old Windows server.

I've tried:

- Printing in raw format (`-o raw`) via the command line.
- Various drivers for the printer in cups.
- Setting a MaxJobTime in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
- Setting a Timeout in /etc/cups/cupsd.conf.
- Text only driver in CUPS.
- Raw driver in CUPS.
- Spun up a docker container (docker.io/pklaus/brother_ql_web:latest) which prints to the label printer with absolutely no issues.

Of course, I have restarted the service between each change. I can print a .PDF to a different printer on the network with no problems. After three days of this, reading every suggestion I can find and trying most of them, I am stumped.

Does anyone have any advice on how to get CUPS to release the job after it finishes printing?

*** Additional information ***

I changed the log level to collect debugging but have seen no errors.

Any thoughts about what tells CUPS that a job is complete?

Driver information:

- Description: Brother QL-820NWB
- Location: Front Office
- Driver: Brother QL-820NWB CUPS (grayscale)
- Connection:
  dnssd://Brother%20QL-820NWB%20%5B405bd82534a4%5D._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-0080775c519b
- Defaults: job-sheets=none, none
  media=custom_28.96x89.83mm_28.96x89.83mm sides=one-sided

lpstat -t give me:

```
scheduler is running
no system default destination
device for brother4: dnssd://Brother%20QL-820NWB%20%5B405bd82534a4%5D._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=e3248000-80ce-11db-8000-0080775c519b
device for Brother_QL_820NWB: implicitclass://Brother_QL_820NWB/
brother4 accepting requests since Thu 18 May 2023 07:01:05 AM EDT
Brother_QL_820NWB accepting requests since Thu 18 May 2023 06:55:43 AM EDT
printer brother4 now printing brother4-89.  enabled since Thu 18 May 2023 07:01:05 AM EDT
        Waiting for job to complete.
printer Brother_QL_820NWB is idle.  enabled since Thu 18 May 2023 06:55:43 AM EDT
brother4-89             root              1024   Thu 18 May 2023 07:01:05 AM EDT
```

Comment: You might get a hint by looking at `/var/log/cups/*`. Read `man cupsd.conf`, you can make the logs mote verbose. Which printer driver are you using? Do `lpstat -t`.Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing Sysyem) GUI by pointing your browser  to `http://localhost:631`.
  
You can detect, add, and manage printers from the `Admin` tab, and deal with individual printers from the `Printers` tab. You can set the system default printer.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309200/cups-printer-stuck-at-waiting-for-job-to-complete has an answer.

The connection type "AppSocket/HP JetDirect" was the answer.